# How to ensure dalvik-cache and lib are linked to SD on boot?

Tags: htc-desire, boot, link2sd

Recently, I upgraded my [htc-desire](/questions/tagged/htc-desire) with a bigger SD Card with a partition of 512Mo on it.

I installed [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) to place apps on SD card `ext4` partition.

Then I had to create by hand, the mount script to have my partition used by [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd). (certainly due to write access on `/system` mountage)

What I wander is if there is a way to ensure that on reboot, linked apps create their dalvik-cache directly on SD. What is happening on startup is that I need to open [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd), select all my apps, and relink everything.

Is it a feature included in the mount script?

Or is it simply the way [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) works?

*PS: what is anoying is that the dalvik-cache takes too much place and can prevent some application from starting correctly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely to be possible in this context, as Dalvik cache has a fixed system-wide location (`/data/dalvik-cache`). So you cannot have "linked apps place *their* dalvik cache directly on SD". Either all or nothing. Take a look at the [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) for alternative approaches which might allow to move *the entire [dalvik](/questions/tagged/dalvik) cache* to your SDCard. But a selective move IMHO is impossible.

<sup>Remark: An exception to this general rule are odexed ROMs, where the `.odex` files sit in the same place as the app, at least for *system apps*. So there *might* be a way to do the same for "user apps" which I have missed.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, that answered my question, for my needs I finnaly added a dummy .dc2sd file on my `/sd-ext` so  `etc/init.d/10apps2sd` script move all the dalvik-cache to sd and nuke the one on internal memory.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Yannick! So just for me to understand: On each boot, that script moves the Dalvik cache for the "marked" apps to SD? Doesn't that mean that on the next boot, Android will re-create it in `/data/dalvik-cache`? If so, what does the move improve (except for "temporary relief")? To me this looks dangerous. Imagine a few apps with a larger `.dex`, and think of low internal storage space when you reboot the device (because you installed one more big app, thinking you had the space) – and now Android rebuilds the `.dex` on internal storage, running out of space.

Comment: The script 10apps2sd from Evervolv Project coming in my ROM mount `/sd-ext/dalvik-cache` as the `/data/dalvik-cache` so all `.dex` goes on sd-card. For the risk of big apps, I'll keep that in mind, I can install them on SD or make the symlinks with link2sd. So if the sd-card is not available those won't prevent system to load as system should have space.

Comment: By the way, my HTC-Desire came with a 148Mo internal storage you might understand the need moving apps and data on external memory.

Comment: One last thing as a feed back, don't let [tag:link2sd] try to link [tag:dalvik-cache] that is already present on sd-card. It will make a loop symlink on itself. :(

Comment: Right: If the app is on sd-ext, and sd-ext is only mounted *after* `boot_completed` (as it is the case with the "normal" SDCard), this problem should not arise as the system should not see those apps. Forgot about that, sorry. And I never doubted the reasons for moving apps to SD :)